# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

While running this command:
-react-native run-android 
I had this error:

[image]

I verified to install sdk tools(26.0.1 , 26.0.2, 23.0.1 and 23.0.2)

my gradle file contains:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.audioexample"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}


dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-sound')
compile project(':react-native-audio')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"

compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

}

Comment: setting your support lib version to 27.1.1 should fix this but why is your target sdk so low? you should be targeting at least 26, is this an old project? edit: `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"` this is the line you want to change to 27.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

In the android gradle file you need to specify the following

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

and then find this text compile `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7"`
and make sure it says compile `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"`

In your build.gradle file add maven url 'https://maven.google' should look like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file add maven url 'https://maven.google.com'

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```